# Centering map with Carto Builder?

Tags: carto, carto-js

In previous versions of Carto it was easy to set the zoom and center-point of a map embed via URL parameters

```
http://<username>.carto.com/viz/<viz_id>/embed_map?zoom=3&center_lat=0&center_lon=0
```

via [source](https://carto.com/docs/faqs/sharing-maps#how-can-i-set-the-position-of-an-embedded-map)

This was a very handy feature as it enabled you to save out a set of maps with different zoom and center-points from the same base map.

Does anyone know how to do this with Carto Builder?

These same query parameters do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parametrization of BUILDER dashboard state is on the roadmap but no dates for a release of that feature, sorry. If you move the map you'll see the URL is updated with an encoded JSON object, but this is not final and may change at any time since it's not a documented/released feature. Sorry for the inconvenience.

**UPDATE**: there's a bit of a hacky way to do this, I've detailed it [here](https://gist.github.com/jsanz/9d72a1a91039e7be0d49db1524cadedb).

Disclaimer: I'm a solutions engineer at CARTO.